# Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2 Firmware Update fails

Tags: thinkpad, firmware, docking-station

I have a ThinkPad P52s with a Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2.

Updating the firmware of the dock shows

```
Can't read Thunderbold controller version, Will skip Thunderbold firmware update!
```

The title of this modal dialog is `Warnning`

Then the update runs the next steps and displays the information

```
Your dock has new firmware can be upgraded, please click [Update] to start firmware upgrade".
```

Then I can click the `Update` button and the next steps are processed.

At the end, an error dialog is displayed with title `Thunderbolt firmware update fail` and text `Error`.

And of course, the firmware is not updated.

The screenshot with the warning is [here](https://paste.pics/38627d6d3a13cae5a0518f3475c32f51) and the log comes at the end.

How can I get the update running?

```
2019/08/23 13:45:00 :----------------------------------------------Begin of Tool--------------------------------------------------
2019/08/23 13:45:00 :GetModuleFileName
2019/08/23 13:45:00 :C:\Users\apm1grb\Downloads\thinkpad_tbt3_gen2_ws_dock_fw_v3164_new (1)\ThinkPad_TBT3_Gen2_WS_Dock_FW_ V3164
2019/08/23 13:45:01 :Installing Filter Driver
2019/08/23 13:45:01 : Call HubIspTool //AFD to install filter driver
2019/08/23 13:45:02 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:03 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:04 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:05 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:06 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:07 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:08 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:09 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:10 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:11 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:12 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:13 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:14 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:15 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:16 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:16 :----Used 15 seconds---
2019/08/23 13:45:16 :Execute HUBIspTool.exe /AFD, ret code=0
2019/08/23 13:45:16 :Wait 3 seconds
2019/08/23 13:45:19 : Call checkHubSpeed to make sure filter driver
2019/08/23 13:45:19 :CheckHubSpeed
2019/08/23 13:45:20 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:45:20 :----Used 1 seconds---
2019/08/23 13:45:20 :Execute HUBIspTool_NEW_CheckHubSpeed2_Silent.exe, ret code=3
2019/08/23 13:45:21 Smiley Very Happyock connection checking...
2019/08/23 13:45:21 :Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Found!
2019/08/23 13:45:21 :Reading version from chip...
2019/08/23 13:45:27 :filter driver existed!
2019/08/23 13:45:27 Smiley Very Happyelete previosly DataOutput.bin
2019/08/23 13:45:28 :try to read dock version from MCU
2019/08/23 13:45:28 :version info not store on MCU
2019/08/23 13:45:28 :Read TBT frimware version from chip...
2019/08/23 13:45:34 :TBT device ID =0
2019/08/23 13:45:34 :Thunderbolt firmware version =00.00
2019/08/23 13:54:54 :Read USB hub firmware version from chip...
2019/08/23 13:54:54 :USB hub1 firmware version =5113
2019/08/23 13:54:54 :USB hub2 version =5113
2019/08/23 13:54:54 :Read PD+MCU firmmware version from chip...
2019/08/23 13:54:54 Smiley Very Happyelete previosly DataOutput.bin
2019/08/23 13:54:56 :Read MCU version from chip
2019/08/23 13:54:56 :Wait 3 seconds
2019/08/23 13:54:59 :MCU firmware version =0.26
2019/08/23 13:54:59 :MCU firmware version =0.26
2019/08/23 13:54:59 Smiley TongueD controller firmware version =1.38.06.03
2019/08/23 13:54:59 Smiley TongueD2 firmware version =1.38.06.03
2019/08/23 13:54:59 :Turn on LP_CTL for DP hub firmware access...
2019/08/23 13:55:00 :Turn on LP_CTL for DP hub firmware access...5 seconds waitting
2019/08/23 13:55:00 :Wait 2 seconds
2019/08/23 13:55:01 :Reading DP hub firmware version from chip...
2019/08/23 13:55:03 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:55:04 :Main pgress= 10, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:55:05 :Main pgress= 20, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:55:05 :----Used 3 seconds---
2019/08/23 13:55:05 :Execute VmmDPTool.exe -v -s -fr, ret code=0
2019/08/23 13:55:05 Smiley Very HappyP hub firmware version =5.04.002
2019/08/23 13:55:05 Smiley Very HappyP hub firmware version =5.04.002
2019/08/23 13:55:06 :Return code=0
2019/08/23 13:55:06 :Wait 2 seconds
2019/08/23 13:55:08 :Audio firmware version=04-0E-90
2019/08/23 13:55:08 :compare version to decide which component need to update
2019/08/23 13:55:08 Smiley TongueD firmware update is required!
2019/08/23 13:55:08 :some firmware update required.
2019/08/23 13:55:12 :read firmware completed!
2019/08/23 13:55:15 :Updating TBT&PD firmware...
2019/08/23 13:55:15 :disabling XHCI...
2019/08/23 13:55:15 :Wait 3 seconds
2019/08/23 13:55:18 :Updating Thunderbolt controller & PD firmware...
2019/08/23 13:55:19 :Main pgress= 71, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:55:20 :Main pgress= 71, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 13:55:20 :----Used 2 seconds---
2019/08/23 13:55:20 :Execute FwUpdateCmd.exe FWUpdate 0 TRDOCK_4300.bin, ret code=517
2019/08/23 13:55:20 :Enabling XHCI...
2019/08/23 13:55:21 :Wait 30 seconds
2019/08/23 13:55:48 :Update TBT&PD fail
2019/08/23 15:44:18 :----------------------------------------------Begin of Tool--------------------------------------------------
2019/08/23 15:44:18 :GetModuleFileName
2019/08/23 15:44:18 :C:\Users\apm1grb\Downloads\thinkpad_tbt3_gen2_ws_dock_fw_v3164_new (1)\ThinkPad_TBT3_Gen2_WS_Dock_FW_ V3164
2019/08/23 15:44:19 :Installing Filter Driver
2019/08/23 15:44:19 : Call HubIspTool //AFD to install filter driver
2019/08/23 15:44:20 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:21 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:22 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:23 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:24 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:25 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:26 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:27 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:28 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:29 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:30 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:30 :----Used 11 seconds---
2019/08/23 15:44:30 :Execute HUBIspTool.exe /AFD, ret code=0
2019/08/23 15:44:30 :Wait 3 seconds
2019/08/23 15:44:32 : Call checkHubSpeed to make sure filter driver
2019/08/23 15:44:32 :CheckHubSpeed
2019/08/23 15:44:33 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 15:44:33 :----Used 1 seconds---
2019/08/23 15:44:34 :Execute HUBIspTool_NEW_CheckHubSpeed2_Silent.exe, ret code=3
2019/08/23 15:44:34 Smiley Very Happyock connection checking...
2019/08/23 15:44:34 :Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Found!
2019/08/23 15:44:34 :Reading version from chip...
2019/08/23 15:44:40 :filter driver existed!
2019/08/23 15:44:40 Smiley Very Happyelete previosly DataOutput.bin
2019/08/23 15:44:41 :try to read dock version from MCU
2019/08/23 15:44:41 :version info not store on MCU
2019/08/23 15:44:41 :Read TBT frimware version from chip...
2019/08/23 15:44:47 :TBT device ID =0
2019/08/23 15:44:47 :Thunderbolt firmware version =00.00
2019/08/23 16:06:52 :Read USB hub firmware version from chip...
2019/08/23 16:06:52 :USB hub1 firmware version =5113
2019/08/23 16:06:52 :USB hub2 version =5113
2019/08/23 16:06:52 :Read PD+MCU firmmware version from chip...
2019/08/23 16:06:52 Smiley Very Happyelete previosly DataOutput.bin
2019/08/23 16:06:55 :Read MCU version from chip
2019/08/23 16:06:55 :Wait 3 seconds
2019/08/23 16:06:58 :MCU firmware version =0.26
2019/08/23 16:06:58 :MCU firmware version =0.26
2019/08/23 16:06:58 Smiley TongueD controller firmware version =1.38.06.03
2019/08/23 16:06:58 Smiley TongueD2 firmware version =1.38.06.03
2019/08/23 16:06:58 :Turn on LP_CTL for DP hub firmware access...
2019/08/23 16:06:58 :Turn on LP_CTL for DP hub firmware access...5 seconds waitting
2019/08/23 16:06:58 :Wait 2 seconds
2019/08/23 16:07:00 :Reading DP hub firmware version from chip...
2019/08/23 16:07:01 :Main pgress= 0, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 16:07:02 :----Used 1 seconds---
2019/08/23 16:07:02 :Execute VmmDPTool.exe -v -s -fr, ret code=0
2019/08/23 16:07:02 Smiley Very HappyP hub firmware version =5.04.002
2019/08/23 16:07:02 Smiley Very HappyP hub firmware version =5.04.002
2019/08/23 16:07:02 :Return code=0
2019/08/23 16:07:02 :Wait 2 seconds
2019/08/23 16:07:04 :Audio firmware version=04-0E-90
2019/08/23 16:07:04 :compare version to decide which component need to update
2019/08/23 16:07:04 Smiley TongueD firmware update is required!
2019/08/23 16:07:04 :some firmware update required.
2019/08/23 16:10:13 :read firmware completed!
2019/08/23 16:12:30 :Updating TBT&PD firmware...
2019/08/23 16:12:30 :disabling XHCI...
2019/08/23 16:12:30 :Wait 3 seconds
2019/08/23 16:12:32 :Updating Thunderbolt controller & PD firmware...
2019/08/23 16:12:33 :Main pgress= 71, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 16:12:35 :Main pgress= 71, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 16:12:36 :Main pgress= 71, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 16:12:37 :Main pgress= 71, RetCode=259
2019/08/23 16:12:37 :----Used 4 seconds---
2019/08/23 16:12:37 :Execute FwUpdateCmd.exe FWUpdate 0 TRDOCK_4300.bin, ret code=517
2019/08/23 16:12:37 :Enabling XHCI...
2019/08/23 16:12:37 :Wait 30 seconds
2019/08/23 16:13:04 :Update TBT&PD fail
```

btw: All these typos in the dialogs and stupid UX are the reality, not wrong pasted here. And this slipshod work seems to be also deep in inside the logic not only the frontend.

Comment: Try running several times (more than once) the auto online update via the Lenovo website: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com > Drivers & Software > Your model > Automatic Driver Update > Start Scan. If this doesn't help, why do you need to update the firmware?

Comment: Are you sure the title of the dialog actually is **Warnning** because that would mean the title didn't spell Warning the correct way.  Likewise, "Your dock has new firmware can be upgraded ....", is grammatically incorrect.  Are you sure about that particular message is word in that way?  I ask for you to clarify these issues not because I can't figure out what they are suppose to say, but to improve the quality fo the question.

Comment: Can you also please provide the specifics about the dock itself?  What firmware revision is it currently using?  What revision are you trying to upgrade to.  This information might already be provided, but I also see some stuff, that isn't what I would expect from the hardware you do properly identify.

Comment: @Ramhound 1: See my last sentence. Yes, these typos and sentences are exactly how it was provided from the system.

Comment: @Ramhound 2: the current firmware version could not be identified. See [this screenshot](https://i.paste.pics/2fb796988ce049e3953e541352e25320.png)

Comment: @harrymc: I like to update because my external displays are not running in a resolution and refresh rate I like to have. My hope is, that a new firmware could fis it. Please see also my other question [Which resolutions and refresh rates are supported from Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2 with Thinkpad P52s?](https://superuser.com/questions/1476802/which-resolutions-and-refresh-rates-are-supported-from-thunderbolt-3-dock-gen-2)

Comment: What exactly is your ThinkPad model and that of the Dock? Use model names as found in this [webpage](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/solutions/pd500265). Where did you get the firmware update and what is it?

Comment: As written in the initial question: ThinkPad P52s and Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2
that should be detailed enough.
Firmware update (ThinkPad_TBT3_Gen2_WS_Dock_FW_ V3164) from the Lenovo support page .. and it is an update for the firmware of the Dock.